# Addition of Renderscript in Android studio 1.0.1 with API @ 21 and SDKTools @ 21.1.2 causes build errors

Tags: android, renderscript

I am attempting to port an Android 4.4 to Android 5.0. My application utilizes Renderscript. Currently the renderscript application is very simple

```
#pragma version(1) // RenderScript version, 1 is the only one for now
#pragma rs java_package_name(com.example.andriod.rs_android_5) // our package
#pragma rs_fp_relaxed
uint16_t *output;
const uint16_t *input;
void __attribute__((kernel)) encrypt(uint16_t In, uint32_t x, uint32_t y){
    output[in] = x*input[in]; 
}
```

my build.gradle looks like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.andriod.rs_android_5"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
        renderscriptTargetApi 21
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

The error I am getting is:
    Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugRenderscript'.

> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
>       /Users/user/Documents/sdk/build-tools/21.1.2/bcc_compat -O3 -o      /Users/user/Documents/Android/rs_android_5/app/build/intermediates/rs/debug/obj/armeabi-v7a/encrypt.o -fPIC -shared -rt-path /Users/user/Documents/sdk/build-tools/21.1.2/renderscript/lib/bc/armeabi-v7a/libclcore.bc -mtriple armv7-none-linux-gnueabi /Users/user/Documents/Android/rs_android_5/app/build/generated/res/rs/debug/raw/bc64/encrypt.bc
>     Error Code:
>       1
>     Output:
>       WARNING: Linking two modules of different data layouts: '/Users/user/Documents/sdk/build-tools/21.1.2/renderscript/lib/bc/armeabi-v7a/libclcore.bc' is 'e-m:e-p:32:32-i64:64-v128:64:128-n32-S64' whereas '/Users/user/Documents/Android/rs_android_5/app/build/generated/res/rs/debug/raw/bc64/encrypt.bc' is 'e-m:e-i64:64-i128:128-n32:64-S128'
>       WARNING: Linking two modules of different target triples: /Users/user/Documents/sdk/build-tools/21.1.2/renderscript/lib/bc/armeabi-v7a/libclcore.bc' is 'armv7-none-linux-gnueabi' whereas '/Users/user/Documents/Android/rs_android_5/app/build/generated/res/rs/debug/raw/bc64/encrypt.bc' is 'aarch64-none-linux-gnueabi'
>       E/bcc     (27923): Unable to compile the source to file /Users/user/Documents/Android/rs_android_5/app/build/intermediates/rs/debug/obj/armeabi-v7a/encrypt.o! (Error loading input bitcode)
>       Failed to compile script!

If I modify my build.gradle to target 20 or lower the error disappears. Has anyone successfully built a Renderscript application targeting API 21?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can't use support mode when targeting API 21 (or higher) right now. If you are intending to actually use API 21+, you need to switch to the native RS APIs instead (and remove the renderscriptSupportModeEnabled).

Comment: Thanks! I totally missed the  renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true. I had just copied/pasted in the renderscript additions to the build.gradle without reading what it was actually doing.

Comment: @Stephen but what if my `minSdkVersion` is 16 and I am using `ScriptIntrinsicBlur` ?

Comment: The RS TargetAPI is independent of minSdkVersion, and should work just fine all the way back to 8 actually (even for the intrinsics). Please just set it to 20 or less, and everything should just work.

Comment: @StephenHines I think that you can update your answer with this comment, setting to sdk < 20 works fine.

Comment: I'm setting the renderscript target to API 20, but gradle still complains at me saying that support mode isn't supported with target 21+. My app targets API 23.

Comment: I think that anything 21+ is unsupported for the compatibility library today. We should have an SDK update with support for 64-bit in the near future.