# How to use android.support.v8 in buildToolsVersion 23

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

```
I want to use  android.support.v8  .so in build.gradle defaultConfig :

compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion '23.0.0'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.lengyue.trabsformations"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    renderscriptTargetApi 23
    renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
}
```

but wehn I run it ,Android Studio reported an error :

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'D:\Program Files\Java\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

I modif SDK and buildToolsVersion to 22. kike this:

```
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.lengyue.trabsformations"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    renderscriptTargetApi 22
    renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
}
```

them run it .  they run normally.

Who can tell me why? and wat should I do in version 23 ?

Comment: Did you updated support repository

Comment: @Lengyue I think [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27559059/892788) will answer your question

Answer (score 1):

Do you have dependencies? If not try this

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.project"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
}
```