# Renderscript support mode is not currently supported with renderscript target 21+

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, google-play-services

Now I'm working with GCM and when I'm adding `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.0.0-alpha3'` to projects `build.gradle` for `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` in apps `build.gradle` the compiler throws a warning because of that ain't able to build the project

```
Warning:Renderscript support mode is not currently supported with renderscript target 21+
```

and when i remove `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.0.0-alpha3'` it works fine .I'm following the [official](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/tree/master/android/gcm) quick start GCM sample application of google and i build it as a separate project and it too working fine .this happening when am trying to add the feature into my app.Any one know what's going wrong ?

Comment: This [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27558999/addition-of-renderscript-in-android-studio-1-0-1-with-api-21-and-sdktools-21) may be similar to what you are looking for.